# Are there any web frameworks on top of EventMachine?

Tags: ruby, node.js, event-handling, web-frameworks, eventmachine

Are there any web frameworks on top of EventMachine? So far, I've found [Fastr](https://github.com/chrismoos/fastr) and [Cramp](https://github.com/lifo/cramp). Both seem to be outdated.

Moreover, Googling how to setup Rails + EventMachine, returns a limited amount of results.

NodeJS is really nothing new. Evented I/O has been around for a very long time (Twisted for Python and EventMachine for Ruby). However, what attracts me to NodeJS, is the implementations that are built on top of it.

For example. NodeJS has [TowerJS](http://towerjs.org/). Among plenty others. Perhaps, this is one of the many contributing reasons to its trending factor.

What I like most about TowerJS, is its Rails-like structure. Is there anything like it for EventMachine?

Comment: thin runs eventmachine and rails, you can wack some middleware at the front to handle file uploads and messaging and use rails for the rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find [async sinatra](https://github.com/raggi/async_sinatra) interesting

Answer (score 3):

[Goliath](https://github.com/postrank-labs/goliath) is an open source version of the non-blocking (asynchronous) Ruby web server framework.

Comment: Goliath seems a bit bare. Is there anything Rails-like?

Answer (score 1):

Besides EventMachine and the others mentioned here, there's [vert.x](http://vertx.io/). I'm not sure how much of a "web framework" it is, but its site shows examples for a simple app like one might write in Sinatra.